# LibGDX ModelInstance - can't reset scale, setting the transform while scaled deforms the model

Tags: libgdx

Is there any way to reset a modelInstance's scale or set a modelInstances position without using `transform.set`? I'm making a 3D monster maker, When a part is selected a set of 3D arrows move to the part and become visible allowing the part to be dragged around. It's come to my attention that setting an arrow's position while scaled heavily deforms the arrow for whatever reason. This is a huge problem as I need the arrows to be different sizes depending on the size of the part. [Without setting position](https://youtu.be/U4tO7d70ZgM), [with setting position](https://youtu.be/seY8rrSdc2s). Using `transform.set` on a non-scaled ModelInstance (or one scaled by 1) works fine.

I thought a solution would be to reset the size of the arrow before moving it and then re-scaling it after it was moved but there doesn't seem to be any method to do this and using `transform.scale(-currentScale, -currentScale, -currentScale)` inverts the arrow and increases its size rather than decreasing it.

Here is how I change the arrow's position: `arrow[j].transform.set(modelInstance[i].transform.getTranslation(new Vector3(), arrow[j].transform.getRotation(new Quaternion());`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I did some logging and found that scaling changes all values within the matrix4 not just the size of the modelInstance. I didn't find a way to only scale rotation but I figured a way around this: I created an empty Matrix4 and set that to a copy of the arrows matrix before scaling. When the arrows need to be positioned at a part I set the arrow's matrix to the baseMatrix, used transform.set to change the arrows' position, and then rescaled the arrow.

```java
    if(Intersector.intersectRayBoundsFast(pickRay, modelInstance[i].boundingBox)) {
        modelInstance[i].transform.getTranslation(modelInstance[i].position);//get the part's position and store it
        for(int j = 0 ; j < 3 ; j++) {
            arrow[j].transform = arrow[j].baseTransform.cpy();//reset the arrows transform
            arrow[j].transform.getRotation(arrow[j].rotation);//get the arrow's (unscaled) rotation and store it
            arrow[j].transform.set(modelInstance[i].position, arrow[j].rotation);//set the arrow's position and rotation
            arrow[j].changeSize('S');//rescale the arrow
        }

        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use transform.scale(1f/currentScale, 1f/currentScale, 1f/currentScale) to revert the scaling or the function ModelInstance.calculateTransforms()